# how to perform addition operation using string template in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

1.Sample input:

```js
let arr = [1,3];
console.log(`Addition is ${arr[0]? arr[0]: 0} + ${arr[1] ? arr[1] : 0}`);
```

2.Sample input:

```js
let arr = [{card:0, cash:0},{card:1, cash: 2}];
 for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
     console.log(`No. of payments ${(arr[i].card || 0)} + ${(arr[i].cash ||  0)}`);
}
```

Comment: I dont get it...

Comment: Why are you using string template if you dont have a string

Comment: same as @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I dont get what you trying to do. actually it logs "1+3" but the same output should be '3' ...

Comment: @srinivas I added answer with different ways to achieve that, hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is what you are looking for...

```js
let arr = [1,3];
console.log(`Adittion is ${arr[0]? arr[0]: 0} + ${arr[1] ? arr[1] : 0}`);

// or 

console.log(`Addition is ${(arr[0]? arr[0]: 0) + (arr[1] ? arr[1] : 0)}`);

// If the socond one is the one you wanted, you can do it using reduce instead summing all positions

console.log(`Addition is ${arr.reduce((a,b)=>a+b)}`);
```

**Update**
This is your second sample. This is completely different because in here you are not using an array of numbers, you are using an array of objects and the implementation is not the same.

PD: Consider asking a new question when is something different from what you asked before

```js
//In Your second sample you are using an array of objects, not an array of numbers so the implementation is different

let arr = [{card:0, cash:0},{card:1, cash: 2}];

arr.map(a=>{console.log(`No. of payments ${a.card + a.cash}`)})

//If you only want the total it would be

console.log(`No. of payments ${arr.map(a=>a.card + a.cash).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)}`)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution @Luis Felipe

Comment: For readability's sake, I would also consider setting the result to a variable someplace, so your string is just `\`Addition is ${result}\``

Comment: Your solution will not work for second sample input @Luis Felipe De Jesus Munoz

Comment: That is because in your second sample is an object instead an array and therefore is another question. Ill update my answer but for the next time consider asking another question

Answer (score 1):

To make it work you need to put **both operands** inside the same brackets

```
`${(arr[0] || 0) + (arr[1] || 0)}`
```

Also I used the `||` (**operand selector operator** or **logical or**) to achieve the same result (I think it's more readable).

Comment: This will not work for example 2. @Rodrigo Ferrerira

Comment: @srinivas why do you say that it will not work for example 2, and what should be the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

**Ways to achieve this :**

```js
let arr = [1,3];

// Method 1
console.log('Addition is ', (arr[0] ? arr[0]: 0) + (arr[1] ? arr[1] : 0));

// Method 2
console.log(`Addition is ${(arr[0]? arr[0]: 0) + (arr[1] ? arr[1] : 0)}`);

// Method 3
var sum = [1,3].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log('Addition is ', sum);

// Method 4
function addition(...elements) {
    let total = 0;
    for (const elem of elements) {
        total += elem;
    }
    return total;
}

console.log('Addition is ', addition(...arr));
```